# Faster way to group email-date pairs by date without many nested for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given list of pairs (email-date):

```
['ann_osman@mail.com', '2 august 1976'], 
['jz_neo@mail.com', '3 august 2001'], 
['keyes_signak@mail.com', '2 october 2001'], 
['cassadi_algazi@hotmail.com', '2 october 2001'], 
['karmen_algazi@aol.com', '2 august 2001']]
```

I need to turn it into dictionary grouped by dates (one date → many emails).

I can do it with for loops:

```
def emails_for_one_date():


        for each_entry in email_date_table:


                for each_date in each_entry:
                        current_date_as_key = each_date

                        for each_entry2 in email_date_table:
                                list_emails = []
                                if each_entry[1] == current_date_as_key:
                                        list_emails.append( each_entry[0])
                                date_for_emails_dict[current_date_as_key] = list_emails
        print("------------------- dict here")
        print(date_for_emails_dict)
```

But Python is such a powerful language, I want to know the 'pythonic' way of doing it!
I suspect it can be one line.

Comment: Your code actually does more than advertised: the e-mail addresses are all added as keys to `date_for_emails_dict` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good function will should accept the data as a parameter and return the resulting data structure.  Call `print(emails_by_date(email_date_table))` to put it all together.

Two Pythonic techniques you want to use are:

- [`dict.setdefault(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), which gets rid of the need for `if`, as well as the requirement for the input to be grouped chronologically
- [Multiple assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) in the for-loop, which removes the ugly `[0]` and `[1]` indexing:

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.
>   
>   The function could be written as:

```
def emails_by_date(pairs):
    ret = {}
    for email, date in pairs:
        ret.setdefault(date, []).append(email)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 2):

As you suspect, there is an easier way. The first thing we'll need is `defaultdict` from the `collections` module.

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

A `defaultdict` acts like a dictionary, with the difference that whatever type is specified upon construction will be used as a default if a given key does not exist in the dictionary. For example:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d[1]
0
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 0})
```

With a normal dictionary, this would give you a `KeyError` (as 1 did not exist). With a `defaultdict`, it sees that 1 does not exist, and inserts an `int()` (which is 0).

In our case, we're going to want a list to be the default:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

Given that we have a list of pairs, we can just grab each of name and date out of the list as we go:

```
for name, date in email_date_table:
```

Now we just lookup the `date` key, and append the current `name`:

```
d[date].append(name)
```

If `d[date]` doesn't exist, it will create an empty list and append `name` to it. If it does exist, it will simply give us back the existing list of names that is mapped to by that key.

The whole thing then becomes:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for name, date in email_date_table:
    d[date].append(name)
```

Comment: With `defaultdict`, be aware that simply querying the resulting data structure for non-existent dates will cause it to be littered with empty list entries.

Comment: both answers are great - I did not know that just by creating dictionary with date as key, it puts all corresponding emails in list!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the one-liner, not that it's recommended:

```
email_date_dict = {date: [name for name, date2 in email_date_table if date2 == date] for _, date in email_date_table}
```

It's inefficient (because it iterates over `email_date_table` repeatedly) and not very readable but illustrates how powerful python's list and dictionary comprehensions can be.